# Ignore short characters and specific words in search highlight function

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, explode, implode

I have keyword **"bolding"** function here:

```
$ignore = array ('div', 'class', 'high', 'light', 'highlight');
$keywords = explode(' ', $qsvarus);
$title[$key] = preg_replace('/'.implode('|', $keywords).'/i', '<b>$0</b>', $title[$key]);
$infoo[$key] = preg_replace('/'.implode('|', $keywords).'/i', '<b>$0</b>', $infoo[$key]);
```

The problem is it sometimes catches some of my html tags. How to tell it to ignore everything shorter than 3 letters and certain specific words from $ignore array when `<b></b>` $keywords?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would simply loop around the keywords array first, removing any matches in the ignore array (use in_array) and also any keywords that are 3 characters or less.

Then if you want to make sure you are not in a tag, the following should suffice:

```
/\b(keyword|keyword|keyword)\b(?![^<]*[>])/
```

I've basically appended a negative lookahead:

```
(?![^<]*[>])
```

The regex will match as long as that look ahead for a closing html `>` not preceded by an opening tag `<` doesn't match. I you do get a closing tag, you should be able* to assume that you are inside a tag.

Putting that back into the preg_replace:

```
preg_replace('/\b('.implode('|', $keywords).')\b(?![^<]*[>])/i', '<b>$1</b>', $subject);
```

- This does assume that there isn't an unencoded greater than (`>`)

Comment: Getting error: Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Compilation failed: lookbehind assertion is not fixed length at offset 12. If foreaching it when doing this function with 12 other items. THats why im using $key :)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that lookbehind assertions need to be fixed length. You can do the same with a lookahead. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: As for your foreach loop - without further code I can't really visualise what you are trying to do; are the keywords defined for each key? If not then you just want to loop around removing ignore and < 3 chars outside of that other foreach loop.

Comment: Of course, another option would be to use `preg_replace_callback` and only conditionally apply the bold tags to the replacement when it isn't in the ignore array, or > 3 chars?

Comment: Thanks, no error now, but it still matches html tags :( for example fi theres heyword it higlights div in <div class="highlight-item">. Probably something wrong with regex?

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo - corrected. (Moved the * outside of the character class)

Comment: Further updated to include word boundaries as mentioned by @anubhava